# Finding the Shortest path in undirected weighted graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path

Is there an algorithm for finding the shortest path in an undirected weighted graph?

Comment: [Shortest Path on an Undirected Graph?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1329/shortest-path-on-an-undirected-graph?rq=1) might be interesting.

Comment: This question is incredibly thin and answers can be found on Wikipedia as well as in any basic algorithms textbook. Virtual vote to close.

Answer (score 3):

### All-Pairs-Shortest Path

Given a graph $G = (V, E)$ find the shortest path between *any* two nodes $u,v \in V$. It can be solved by [Floyd-Warshall's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) in time $O(|V|^3).$ Many believe the APSP problem requires $\Omega(n^3)$ time, but it remains open if there exists algorithms taking $O(n^{3 - \delta} \cdot \text{poly}(\log M))$, where $\delta > 0$ and edge weights are in the range $[-M, M]$.

The reasoning for this is upon close examination we see that the APSP problem can be solved by matrix multiplication. If we replace the operators to $\{\text{min}, +\}$ instead of $\{ +, \cdot \}$ we may use the framework for matrix multiplication to compute the solution. What is interesting is if there exists sub-cubic algorithms for the APSP problem, then there exists sub-cubic algorithms for many related graph and matrix problems [1].

---

[1] [Subcubic Equivalences Between Path, Matrix, and Triangle Problems](http://www.stanford.edu/~rrwill/tria-mmult.pdf)

Comment: The Dijkstra's and Bellman Ford's are best known algorithms for graphs with Non-negative and negative edge weights respectively. But, has any one proved a non-trivial lower bound for these problems which matches the best known upper bound? If not, then these are not optimal.

Comment: You should also mention [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm), which solves the same problem as Djikstra's but much faster, if you have a decent distance-heuristic available to you.

Comment: @rizwanhudda, I should make clear that optimal in my answer, is with respect to the size/weight of the path, not in runtime.

Comment: Having re-read the OP questions, I realize why the confusion arose. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: "Shortest" already means "optimal".

Comment: Ok, under your edit yes. I wasn't sure if the OP wanted  optimal-time algorithm that gives (implied optimal) solution, or just _an_ algorithm to give the optimal solution.